# Pie Charts custom color

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit, pie-chart

I'm trying to develop a custom control for charting.

I'm using the WPF toolkit, but I can't find how it is possible (is it?) to set a specific color for each piece in a pie chart.

I don't understand why they made this one so complex. Many applications are using specific colors for existing categories, wouldn't be reasonable to use the same in the charting?